# ASP.net main thread block during long running process

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, block, program-entry-point

I have a page from where a user can upload excel sheet and add all data into database. If any user run this page and data upload is in progress other users are not able to access application.
Application is hosted in IIS7.

Comment: What is your configuration? Do you use different server for database and IIS7, processors per server, which upload component etc.

Comment: windows server 2008 R2, Intel Xeon with 2 processor, 32 GB ram, WEB is hosted on IIS7 , both web and database are on same server and upload process is simple as used in asp.net but data processing ( saving and checking ) is taking long time.